# Will a setTimeout keep a function from being garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

Assume I have the following `myFunction` & `setTimeout` duo

```
function myFunction(){
    var am_i_eaten = 'ffdfjdhsfhs';

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(am_i_eaten);
    },3000);
}

myFunction();
```

Will the `setTimeout` keep the scope of `myFunction` alive (since it can still print `am_i_eaten` without problem), and prevent it from being garbage collected in my **Node.JS environment**? I believe the behavior to be somewhat different than  the behavior in a browser?

Thanks!

Comment: The variables in the closure will be GC'd after the _setTimeout_ has invoked, unless the GC is really smart and you had some other variable which is not referenceable in the timeout's function (i.e. no use of the identifier, no `eval`ing), in which case that other variable may be _GC'd_. Don't rely on the "smart" bit though, if you're concerned, set the identifier to `null` when you're done with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! So by setting the identifier to null, do you mean I should just do `am_i_eaten = null` at the end of function, after `setTimeout`?

Comment: no, I mean if you have a second variable which is not used in the timeout's function so isn't necessary for the timeout, e.g. `var foo = ["some", "big", "memory", "hog"];`..after finished with _foo_, `foo = null;`

Comment: @PaulS. Ah ok, I understand now. What if I don't want the `setTimeout` to keep the function scope alive at all, though? I want to pass whatever variables or references I need to the `setTimeout`, but still garbage collect the function? Could I wrap the `setTimeout` in an anonymous function?

Comment: To guarantee that behviour the callback needs to be a reference from outside of the function's closure and if you wanted to pass any variables into it then you'd probably need a generator function. `setTimeout`'s 3rd+ params are defined as args for the callback but many implementations don't include that functionality (I don't know in node.js). There comes a point where you need to ask yourself if the overhead of extra function calls is worth the earlier GCing :)

Comment: @PaulS. Gotcha. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond. I guess I'll just stick with setting all identifiers that I'm done with to `null` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have created is a function closure and the variables in that closure will not be garbage collected until after the `setTimeout()` callback runs.

You can conceptually think of the local variables to a function as individual items that are garbage collected only when no other code that can still be called can reach those variables.  So, until after your `setTimeout()` callback runs, the variable `am_i_eaten` is still reachable and will not be garbage collected.

This works identically in the browser and in node.js (its literally the same V8 JS engine in Chrome and node.js).

Comment: Adding to this, testing it on repl on Chrome seems to agree with what jfriend00 is saying. https://repl.it/@DanielKaspo/GrizzledOrchidJavadocs

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho - I changed the second one to use the same wording as the first.  They were supposed to mean the same thing.

Comment: Another thing... The *mark and sweep* GC deletes everything that is not reachable from the global context. Then I think the setTimeout event queue is included in the global context. Obviously it is included. I checked that code worked in my console too, and had it set to 30s. The reference chain is then something like: *global context* --> `function(){console.log(am_i_eaten);}` --> `var am_i_eaten`. I am never 100% sure but hope I had some point here.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho - I'm not sure what you mean by "global context".  Lots of async callbacks are not reachable from the global context.  The variables inside those callbacks are only reachable from within the callback itself - they are not reachable from code running in the global context.

Comment: Ah.. I mean "global object" - *This algorithm assumes the knowledge of a set of objects called roots. In JavaScript, the root is **the global object** ... Starting from the roots, the garbage collector will thus find all reachable objects and collect all non-reachable objects.* ... Mark-and-sweep algorithm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm

Comment: If I remember.. the global object is the `window` object. The variable `am_i_eaten` is then reachable from `window` because it is not collected. It is told that secret variables is not possible in Javascript, but maybe we have it in some seconds?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho - This is not the appropriate place to discuss the gritty details of garbage collection.  `am_i_eaten` is absolutely NOT reachable from `window` or any global context.  It's a PRIVATE local variable that is reachable ONLY from within `myFunction`.  The GC knows how to handle these types of variables.  They are part of the function scope object from when `myFunction` was called and that scope object is kept alive by the timer callback which can still reach that scope (until after that callback executes).  The interpreter itself keeps track of scope objects.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout arbitrary data will be automatically collect by garbage collector once timeout operation done.

Answer (score 0):

**In javascript scope of a function is created when the function is created**. `SetTimeout` takes a callback function which keeps a reference of scope of `myFunction`. So it wont be garbage collected till the callback function is called.